# Min content rows when grid is stretched out

Tags: css, css-grid

I've got a grid where the first column is an image that spans the full height of the grid. I've got a dynamic collection of rows next to it with text. When the image is tall the row heights expand evenly.

I need to keep the rows only as tall as their content. I expected `min-content` would work but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is this something grid can do without wrapping the paragraph boxes in their own wrapper? Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}

.picture {
  grid-row: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="picture"/>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div class='grid'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="picture"/>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As per your query, you want image height to be the same as a number of dynamic text rows height ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the last row to be `1fr`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
}

.picture {
  grid-row: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="picture"/>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Or span 5 rows instead of 4:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  
}

.picture {
  grid-row: span 5;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="picture"/>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't clear with my initial question. The amount of 'p' items will be dynamic so I can't use figures that define a fixed number of rows. I'll update the question.

Comment: @MattCoady consider my last snippet and use a big number like `span 100`, it will work